# Nativscript platform specific template not working

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Building an app in Nativescript 5.0 for both Android and iOS. For some reason the  and  tags don't seem to work as they should, or i might be doing it wrong.

```
<StackLayout>
<android>
    <ActionBar class="header" flat="true">
        <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
            <app-eon-colors-top></app-eon-colors-top>
            <GridLayout columns="auto, *, auto, auto" rows="2*">
                <Label class="title" col="0" text="{{title}}" verticalAlignment="center"></Label>
                <Label class="icon fa-solid" col="2" text="&#xf2f5;" verticalAlignment="center"></Label>
                <Label class="logout fa-solid" col="3" row="0" text="Logga ut" verticalAlignment="center" (tap)="logout()"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ActionBar>
</android>
<ios>
    <ActionBar class="header" flat="false">
        <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
            <Label class="title" text="{{title}}"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <ActionItem ios.position="right">
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                <Label class="icon fa-solid" text="&#xf2f5;"></Label>
                <Label class="logout fa-solid" ios.position="right" text="Logga ut" (tap)="logout()"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </ActionItem>
    </ActionBar>
</ios>
</StackLayout>
```

When running this template on android it only uses the code in the ios block, but on ios it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's NativeScript Core way of writing platform specific XML. With Angular, you could use directives, there is a [Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/350) that discusses about this problem and also provides sample code to implement this platform specific directive on your project.

**Platform specific structural directive**

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { DEVICE } from "nativescript-angular/platform-providers";

import { Device, platformNames } from "platform";

@Directive({
    selector: "[appIfAndroid]"
})
export class IfAndroidDirective {
    constructor( @Inject(DEVICE) device: Device, container: ViewContainerRef, templateRef: TemplateRef<Object>) {
        if (device.os === platformNames.android) {
            container.createEmbeddedView(templateRef);
        }
    }
}

@Directive({
    selector: "[appIfIos]"
})
export class IfIosDirective {
    constructor( @Inject(DEVICE) device: Device, container: ViewContainerRef, templateRef: TemplateRef<Object>) {
        if (device.os === platformNames.ios) {
            container.createEmbeddedView(templateRef);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you import this directive in your module, then you could use `*appIfAndroid` / `*appIfIos` on any tag.